# Xamarin Android: Google Pay integration and Play Service 16.0.0.0

Tags: android, xamarin.android, stripe-payments, google-pay

So in the Google pay integration with Android, Google says that devices should have play services 16.0 or more. But so far I can only find version upto 14.X.

What gives? has anyone ran into this issue?

I am using Stripe for integration. For some reason, I am getting this exception:
Android.Gms.Common.Apis.ApiException: 10: 
then bunch of anonymized classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the currently available version of `GooglePlayServices` on maven it is `16.1.2`

But if you check NuGet for `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices` with pre-release enabled the latest version available is `70.1501.0-preview2` which if I am not wrong targets the maven version `15.0.1` and since I could not find any release notes in regards to when will be the latest `GooglePlayServices` NuGet would be released I would suggest you will have to wait until it is released.

A quick question though why do you need the latest `GooglePlayServices` I am pretty sure it is not needed for Google Pay integration.

Answer (score 1):

As G.hakim points out, you need a version that supports Google Pay, not necessary the latest, although it's recommended to inspect and update the version of the libraries you typically use.

Google Pay specific logs are shared at a system level. That is, you need remove the filter in the logs to show all logs. If you then filter the output with the term "wallet" you should be able to find elements of the type `WalletMerchantError` that provide more details about the specific problem in your configuration / setup.